# alert phone client when update the server database Android

Tags: android, client, server

i build a application client/Server the client is my smartphone and the server is website include database
I ask if there is a method to alert my phone when i effect an changing in the data base of server

Comment: Use Push Notification or Socket Programming to make session between your client/server

Comment: please have you an axampl to how to do this ?

Comment: your question is too broad to answer but you can also use : Google Cloud Messaging for that : https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: i didn't get it please can you give a simple example